# How to manage HTTP requests in Akka?

Tags: scala, akka

I'm using Spray in my application and from the examples I've see on Github it looks like people handle HTTP requests in Akka by passing the HTTPContext object around to all the actors and calling `onComplete { }` on the Future in the last actor.

Is sending the context deep down in the application really a good idea ? This way every event object will have a context parameter.

How do we handle HTTP requests & response properly in Akka? I've read [this](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2014/01/three-flavours-of-request-response.html) article but I would like to know people's thoughts who run Akka in production on the right way of achieving this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer to use the ask pattern in the Spray service, and the onSuccess directive, e.g.:

```
trait MyService extends HttpService {

  def worker: ActorRef

  implicit def timeout:Timeout

  implicit def ec:ExecutionContext

  def askWorker: Future[String] = (worker ? "Hello").mapTo[String]

  def myRoute = path("/") {
    get {
      onSuccess(askWorker){
        case str => complete(str)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then a concrete actor such as:

```
class ServiceActor extends MyService with Actor {

  implicit val ec = context.system

  implicit val timeout = Timeout(3 seconds)

  val worker = context.actorOf(Props[WorkerActor])

  override def actorRefFactory = context.system

  def receive = runRoute(myRoute)
}
```

I like this pattern rather than passing the request context around since it means that the other actors don't have to have any concept of Http. The service could be completely replaced with a different protocol. In this example the worker actor is can be something like:

```
class WorkerActor extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case "Hello" => sender() ! "Hello World"
  }
}
```

Comment: What if the WorkerActor needs to call Actor2 and Actor2 calls Actor3 and Actor3 calls Actor4 and Actor4 is the one that returns a response. Do I still use the ask pattern in each Actor calling another actor ?

Comment: At this point it becomes a regular Akka design problem/decision with a few options. If the worker actor needs to delegate to another, it could send a message including the actor ref of the sender it received the original message from. Any actor which sends a message to the actorRef of the original `sender()` will complete the Future in the Service, due to the way the ask pattern works.